# Order of Execution of Multiple HttpServerFilters

Tags: micronaut

If i have two `HttpServerFilter` implementations, one annotated with `@Filter("/**")` and another with `@Filter("/abc/**")`, how does micronaut handle this?

In my use case, I want micronaut to execute both and execute the filter with `@Filter("/**")` before `@Filter("/abc/**")`. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you needed to use the @Order annotation with @Filter you can give the order precedence as the parameter
example

```
@Ordered(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

note that lower the value higher the precedence

Comment: Thanks @WorkaroundNewbie. I found another way to achieve this was to simply implement the `getOrder` method within the filter implementation as `HttpServerFilter` extends the `Ordered` interface. Details here: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/filter/HttpServerFilter.html

Comment: Just to add that the enum io.micronaut.http.filter.ServerFilterPhase contains the numbers that belongs to each set of filters... FRIST, METRICS, TRACING, SESSION, SECURITY... so it easy to place the filter in a specific phase:

`public int getOrder() {return ServerFilterPhase.SECURITY.after();}`